# order keyvaluepair using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following list keyvaluepair

```
   var countryList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();
```

which I then populate with a while loop from the db something like this

```
   countryList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("cname",1));
```

I then want to query it using linq and order it at the same time, I have this

```
var lst = from s in countryList
      orderby s.[0]
      select s;
```

As you can guess it doesn't work, I know why it's the s.[0] but can someone tell me what the correct syntax is?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you order it in the first place, the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lst = from s in countryList
      orderby s.Key
      select s;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make it in a one line instead

```
var sortedCountryList = countryList.OrderBy(s=>s.Key);
```

and if you only want the country names in a list

```
var sortedCountryList = countryList.OrderBy(s=>s.Key).Select(s=>s.Value);
```